# Loss of power during factory reset

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, factory-defaults

So, I started a factory reset through windows settings
on my laptop while in college, not realising that it would take ages. My battery on my laptop doesn't work, so when I unplugged it all to go home, the computer instantly turns off.

Theres a couple of questions here,

1. What would happen when I turn it back on?
2. What, if I need to, would I have to do to make my computer work again?

Comment: OEM Factory Reset of Windows Reset.  [edit\ your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound ?????

Comment: @LegacyCoding depends on which phase it was at the time of power-off, if it was in preparing phase - then it might boot again else i do not think it will; (just turn on your laptop to see - how lucky you are!!) ; my suggestion - grab a win USB and install

Comment: @Madhubala it said "Resetting this PC xx%"

Comment: What part of my question was confusing?  Did you use an OEM function to restore the system to a factory setting or did you Reset Windows from within Windows using the built-in feature.  What you used will make a huge different to the answer to this question.  A comment that simply indicates "???" is not clear.  You should [edit] your question and specify exactly what you used.

Comment: @Ramhound  I dont know what OEM means, but i did it thru windows settings

Comment: Original Equipment Manufacture (OEM).  If you performed a Reset within Windows, then that isn't called a "factory reset", a factory reset would be using a OEM provided image.  Windows Reset using an image that exists on every Windows installation, it also can download a default non-customized Windows image, in more recent versions of Windows 10.  Windows typically is forgiving with regards to these operations, it more likely will resume, but it also depends entirely on the stage it was on.  The worst case you will have to reinstall Windows.  Did you select the option to keep your files?

Comment: @Ramhound no I told it to delete all my files, as i backed up everything essential

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-windows-10-pc-factory-settings

Comment: @GloriaGu thank you, but ive already done all that, its just the fact that it lost power and i dont know if it would break my computer

Comment: In this case, I suggest you to perform a clean reinstallation of Windows via a bootable USB WinPE stick. This is the only way I can think of to make your computer work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my computers fine, it just took me through all the setup questions, so it clearly had finished the reset and the only thing it was left doing was deleting all my files still, this meant that i had 2 windows files `windows` and `windows.old`. Computer works fine and i can use it perfectly