# Windows 10 login after reset

Tags: windows-10, login, reset

I have recently reset my windows 10 using the reset option in the settings app, and when it restarted, it took me to the normal login screen instead of the setup area, and wont let me log in with my email and password. Is there some sort of default user I can log into or even a way to log into my email on my computer. Ive used my microsoft login but I don't know if thats what you need to use.

Comment: If your reset process went successfully you should have gone through a normal first-time setup process. If you did not get the normal first time login process your reset did not proceed properly and you should probably try some sort of repair process on your system.

Comment: In order to provide further advise you will need to tell us exactly what you mean when you say you reset the device. On the Reset screen on my computer there are three primary options, and Reset itself has at least 2 sub-options. What you should expect following that may depend on what you selected. Further, you will need to tell us whether you had used your Microsoft account to login to your computer previously.

Comment: @music2myear I used the reset through the windows settings app, and just told it do delete/reset everything back to the original settings and delete all of my files too. This was the second time I did this as my computer lost power halfway through the first time (https://superuser.com/questions/1619864/loss-of-power-during-factory-reset), but the first time it went through the set up sequence, and the second time, it did not, it just went to the login screen, and ive tried my microsoft account details, which didnt work.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to change the passwords of Windows 10 PCs by messing with System32 files. It will allow you to open a command prompt from the login screen, and that can let you into the computer. I should start by saying that this does not work with Bitlocker protected boot drives.

The first thing you need to do is create a Windows install USB or Disc. Then follow these steps

1. Turn off the computer
2. Insert a Windows 10 install USB
3. Boot from the USB
   a.  To access the boot menu, boot into BIOS by mashing f2 or delete immediately after pushing the power button.
   b.  Press the key for the boot menu, usually f8
   c.  Select the USB drive
4. On the first Windows install screen, select next
5. On the bottom left, select repair computer
6. Select System Image Recovery
7. When the Re-Image your Computer screen comes up, select next
8. Select Advanced
9. Select Install a Driver
10. Select OK
11. Select the System Drive, then This PC, then Windows, then System32
12. Navigate to the Magnify file, and rename it Magnify1
13. Navigate to the cmd file, and rename it Magnify
14. Right click the menu, and refresh. Check that the name changes took.
15. Reboot the computer
16. On the sign in screen, select ease of access icon. Select the Magnify option.
    a.  This will bring up a command prompt with admin access
17. Type the command “net user administrator /active:yes
    a.  Press enter, the prompt should tell you the command completed successfully
18. Reboot the PC
19. Select the new administrator account
20. Press the Windows key+R to bring up the Run window
21. Type “control userpasswords2”
    a.  Press enter
22. Select the user account you need to access
23. Select Reset Password
24. Type a new password, and confirm
25. Shutdown the PC
26. Boot back into the recovery window using the USB drive
27. Undo the changes to the System32 folder by renaming magnify1 to magnify, and magnify to cmd
28. Shutdown the PC, and remove the USB drive
29. Remove the administrator account by opening a Command Prompt window as administrator, and typing the command “net user administrator /active:no” then press enter
    a.  On next boot, the administrator account will be gone

This should allow you to strip the password off of the other account, from the control panel.

Comment: Okey, ive just got my Boot USB but f2 and f8 brings up diagnostics, and delete does nothing, so im stuck on step 3

Comment: The other option would be to boot into recovery mode and select the option to repair the computer using a USB. This is done by turning off the computer from the login screen by pressing the power button and shift at the same time.

Comment: This should in no way be the first method you try. Windows 10, on reset, should take you through a normal first account setup process. There is no reason, if the reset process went successfully, to go through a difficult manual reset process that involves, literally, breaking things inside your computer.

Comment: “Should” take you through a regular setup process, but didn’t. If his windows was behaving normally, then he wouldn’t be on this website. Not saying my solution was the best option or anything either. If you have a better option, please feel free to share it. I by no means know everything about Windows, so if you have any ideas feel free to collaborate.